# What is this error undefined reference to 'xdr_numbers' in RPC

Tags: c, rpc

power.x

```
struct numbers
{
  int number;
  int power;
};

program POWER_PROG {
    version POWER_VERS {
            int power(numbers) = 1;
    } = 1;
} = 0x31415926;
```

client.c

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <rpc/rpc.h>
#include "power.h"

main(argc, argv)
int argc;
char **argv;
{
CLIENT *cl; /* rpc handle */
char *server;

int *result;

    numbers num;


if (argc != 2) {
    fprintf(stderr, "usage:  %s hostname\n", argv[0]);
    exit(1);
}
server = argv[1];   /* get the name of the server */

result = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int));

/* create the client handle */
if ((cl=clnt_create(server, FACT_PROG, FACT_VERS, "udp")) == NULL) 
{
    /* failed! */
    clnt_pcreateerror(server);
    exit(1);
}



num.number=5;
num.power=3;

/* call the procedure bin_date */
if ((result=fact_1(&num, power, cl))==NULL) {
    /* failed ! */
    clnt_perror(cl, server);
    exit(1);
}
printf("Factorial returned from server is : %d\n", *result);

clnt_destroy(cl);   /* get rid of the handle */
exit(0);
}
```

server.c

```
 #include <rpc/rpc.h>
 #include "power.h"

 int temp;
 int *power_1_svc(numbers *num, struct svc_req *rqstp)
 {
    temp = 1;
    int i;

    for(i=1;i<=num->power;i++)
        temp = temp * (num->number);

    return &temp;
  }
```

In the above code, there is only one error occurring:

```
/tmp/cc604P8X.o: In function `power_prog_1':
power_svc.c:(.text+0x4f): undefined reference to `xdr_numbers'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I compiled power.x file using the command: rpcgen power.x
It generated all the files. But when I tried compiling server code, it gives the above error.

```
 gcc -o server.out -DPRC_SVC_FG server.c power_svc.c
```

How to resolve this error?

Comment: It probably means that you're missing a library when building. How do you build? What libraries do you link with? Have you tried changing the order of the libraries (on POSIX platforms like Linux the order matters)?

Comment: The above code works fine, when passing single argument to function on server. But when I am using structure to pass the arguments it is giving the above error.

Answer (score 0):

you most likely forgot to add into the makefile the xdr file (the one that contains the structure definition):

```
 gcc -o server.out -DPRC_SVC_FG server.c power_svc.c power_xdr.c
```

instead of
`gcc -o server.out -DPRC_SVC_FG server.c power_svc.c`